# Get profile image from Azure Ad auth

Tags: azure, passport.js, azure-authentication

Using this for auth against azure: https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2/blob/master/README.md

The returned data is:

```
{ aud: 'ed847aae-15cb-eee-954e-ww',
  iss:
   'https://sts.windows.net/817478-8d3c-4736-8b54-7f2d9fa20e/',
  iat: 1566472055,
  nbf: 1566472055,
  exp: 1566475955,
  amr: [ 'pwd' ],
  family_name: 'qwe',
  given_name: 'qwe',
  ipaddr: 'qwe07',
  name: 'qwe',
  oid: 'qq',
  onprem_sid: 'abc',
  sub: 'abc',
  tid: 'abc',
  unique_name: 'xx@xx.xx',
  upn: 'xx@xx.no',
  ver: '1.0' }
```

There is no profile image url here. How do I fetch the avatar image?

Comment: What is the avatar image refer to?

Comment: If it refers to profilePhoto, you need to call graph api to get it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: are you referring to thumbnail_photo claim? The following doc may help you: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping.md#table-1-json-web-token-jwt-restricted-claim-set

Comment: Hi Joe, any update for this issue?